# jQuery Validate - display one warning for the same types of errors

Tags: jquery, validation, message, repeat

I have a simple form that has several input elements that are required:

```
$("input").each(function(index, elem) {
   var rules = {
     required:true
   }
   $(elem).rules("add", rules);
});
```

And I want to place all error messages in some div, like this:

```
    <div id="errorContainer" class="inputGreska">
        There are some errors. Please correct the following:
        <ul id="errorLabelContainer"></ul>
    </div>
```

So, I did the following:

```
    $("#forma").validate({
       errorClass: "red",
       errorContainer: "#errorContainer",
       errorLabelContainer: "#errorLabelContainer",
       wrapper: "li",
       errorElement: "div"
    });
```

The problem is the following:

If the user forgets to fill more than one input - within error container there will be the same warnings repeated. So, if the user forgets to fill 3 fields, there will be:

- This field is required.
- This field is required.
- This field is required.

Is it possible to show just one error message, like this:

- Fields marked by asterisks (*) are required

  no matter how many elements the user has forgotten to fill.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you're question right you are wanting to display one error message for a form validation even though it has multiple errors, i would try using the showErrors() callback defined in JQuery validate.

`showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        $("#errorContainer").html("Please enter all required fields with an asterisk*.");
    }`

Have pulled together a quick fiddle to show you a working example    http://jsfiddle.net/mvz0c2am/  , hope this helps.